# code from test can not access main on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I faced strange problem.

problem is 'test' folder can not access to class that located in 'main'.

they are same module under 'app' so I believe they should be accessed, but they are not.

even test can run successfully. only android studio IDE can not find the symbols

I tried invalidate caches but it doesn't works for me.

it would be good if I can post my build.gradle, but I could not because of policy of my company.

but I can answer if you give me a question.

thanks

Comment: Sounds unusual. I would ensure it was a Gradle problem not an IDE problem by running your test compilation from the command line (presumably `./gradlew testCompile`) and see if that works.

Comment: thanks for comment. but I don't have testCompile task so I ran other tasks that same with active build variant. and still not works

Comment: Are you sure that your test and main sources are in the proper folders according to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout?

Comment: yep. android studio recognizes test folder and everything works find except cannot find symbol error in IDE. even compilation works well